# How to batch split images using Image Magick

Tags: windows-10, batch, imagemagick, image-editing

I want split few `bmp` images using imagemagick commandline on windows. For the new images, the original file name has to be suffixed with partnumber (eg `_01` , `_02`).

I tried it in the following way, but its not working. Kindly help.

```
magick  convert *.bmp -crop 2x1@  -set filename:f '%t_%d.%e'  +repage  +adjoin  BMP3:'%[filename:f]'
```

Supplement question:

My original bmp image is of size 32MB but when I individually split the image into 2 parts using image magick. Each image is <1MB. Isn't each image supposed to be close to 16MB? Is it reducing the image quality? I don't want to reduce the image quality. How do I retain the size (on the disk)?

Comment: "How do I retain the size?". By size do you mean "horizontal x vertical" or "size on disk"?  Is the renaming working?

Comment: Do you have to have the `'`?

Comment: @somebadhat: size on the disk. I edited and clarified my question.

Comment: @somebadhat: No. Nothing of that sort is required. I don't know what's the role of `'`. I saw that's how its being used in examples on internet. So I copied it.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:  Excluding "size on disk" does this do everything you want?

cmd:

```
set "options=-crop 2x1@ +repage" 
rem md crop
rem FOR %f IN (*.bmp) DO convert "%f" %options% "crop\%~nf_%d.bmp"
FOR %f IN (*.bmp) DO convert "%f" %options% "%~nf_%d.bmp"
```

script:

```
set "options=-crop 2x1@ +repage" 
rem md crop
rem FOR %%f IN (*.bmp) DO convert "%%f" %options% "crop\%%~nf_%%d.bmp" 
FOR %%f IN (*.bmp) DO convert "%%f" %options% "%%~nf_%%d.bmp"
```

[bmp3](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#bmp)

[convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

[quality](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality)

[color](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colors)